# Как подсчитать общий хэш для нескольких файлов?

Tags: python, файлы, хеширование

Скрипт обрабатывает входные файлы, выделяет нужное и из него формирует "контент". Я сравниваю с сохраненным хэшем и если совпадает, то значит обработка не пострадала от изменений в ПО. Как быть если контент формируется в виде 2 файлов? Пока просто сортирую файлы ДО и склеиваю хеши ПОСЛЕ. Думаю что будет лучше просуммировать хэши 2 файлов. Подскажите варианты?

Comment: Суммировать хэши довольно [странная идея](https://www.quora.com/If-you-hash-two-different-files-and-you-add-the-values-will-it-be-the-same-as-if-you-combine-the-two-files-into-one-and-you-hash-the-merge-file). Понятно, что хочется сократить до одной суммы, в принципе никто не запрещает это делать и экспериментировать, но надёжнее просто логику прописать, где оба хэша должны совпадать. Можно её в excel сделать с результирующим TRUE / FALSE.

Comment: Сделайте лучше универсальный список вида: `[[название файла, хэш], [название файла, хэш], ...]` и проверяйте хэш каждого файла отдельно.

Comment: возможно приду к этому варианту :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берете [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html), создаете объект хэша нужного типа, обновляете его содержимым одного файла, потом другого файла, и т.д., в конце получаете общий хэш.

```
import hashlib

hash = hashlib.sha256()
files = sorted(["file1.txt", "file2.txt"])

for file_name in files:
    with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
        hash.update(file.read())

print(hash.hexdigest())
```

Экономный по памяти вариант:

```
import io
import hashlib

hash = hashlib.sha256()
files = sorted(["file1.txt", "file2.txt"])

for file_name in files:
    with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
        while block := file.read(io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE):
            hash.update(block)

print(hash.hexdigest())
```

В идеале в хэш еще нужно добавлять имена файлов, потому что теоретически может случиться ситуация, что файл A не пустой, а файл B пустой, в какой-то момент они меняются содержимым (A становится пустым, а B получает старое содержимое A), а хэш при этом не меняется.

Но вообще лучше конечно хранить список файлов с их хешами, не слепляя все в один хэш.

Comment: Можно при пустом файле добавлять какой-нибудь символ. Тогда если они поменяются местами, символ тоже будет в другом месте.

Comment: @DiMithras а если файл будет не пустой, а с этим символом, то все система сломается. Могут имена файлов в самих файлах попасться. Кучу потенциальных уязвимостей можно найти, если постараться. В идеале просто нужно хранить хэши с именами файлов отдельно, а не слеплять все вместе.

Comment: К последней правке и комментарию: ещё лучше пользоваться стандартными программами вроде [Md5Checker](http://getmd5checker.com/), чем потом разбираться как склейка велась. К тому же с такими суммами можно работать в Total Commander и прочем софте без головной боли. Другое дело, в вопросе "*контент*" файлов, судя по всему как-то отфильтрованный по частям, которые изменяются, но их изменение не критично, так что вполне вероятно ваше решение будет очень кстати.

Comment: hash.update(file.read()) - будет весело по оперативке)

Comment: @eri, согласен, дополнил ответ